# Issue while storing json value with single quotes

Tags: postgresql

I am facing issue while storing jason value which has some text with single quotes.

Below is the scenario,

**My Stored Procedure:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION JsonParse(inputdata json)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
BEGIN

    UPDATE 
        MyTable 
    SET 
        settings_details= inputdata
    WHERE 
        settings_key='my-list'; 

END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;


select * from JsonParse('[{
            "myArray": ["New Text1 ''abcd''", "New Text1 ''abcd''"] 
        },
        {"myArray": ["New Text1 ''abcd''", "New Text1 ''abcd''"]}]');
```

I get the below error :
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "abcd"

I can add extra single quote to abcd and efgh. It solves the issue. But the problem is that i dont have control on the input text to JsonParse procedure. 
The stored procedure should be capable enough to handle this.

May i please know on how to tackle this

Comment: Your edit makes the question nonsensical, because you've escaped the `'`s in the query that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure is not rejecting this, the SQL you are running is malformed.

Try a simpler example:

```
SELECT 'test o'reilly' AS FOO;
```

As the syntax highlighting shows, the SQL parser will think the string is `'test o'`, and the `reilly` is a syntax error.

This is a sign that you are not correctly handling data input into your SQL queries, and are probably vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (what if I supply you with the "JSON" string `{}'); DROP TABLE users; --`).

**Everywhere** that you add data to an SQL query, you need to do one of two things:

- Escape the input using an appropriate function provided by your language or framework. This will *mostly* just be doubling apostrophes, but if implemented properly will ensure there aren't other characters that can break the input based on the database's character set etc.
- Or, use parametrised prepared queries, where you write the SQL with placeholders, and then provide the data as a separate argument, which is transmitted separately, so cannot be mistaken for SQL (and, consequently, doesn't need quotes around strings). In your case, a parametrised query might look like this: `select * from JsonParse(?);` with the execute function taking one parameter.